# How does the Scapular work?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

The description of the Scapular on the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) says:

> Whenever you are downed to 1/2 of your last Heart, Aura around your head temporarily vanishes and you are granted 1 Soul Heart.

Does this effect have any kind of cooldown? Is it a one time only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect did not have any cool down that I could notice and is definitely not one time only. It saved my hide multiple times in adjacent rooms (I was careless).

Comment: I've been more careless than you then, since I managed to be killed in the depths even with the Scapular on. I blame McMillen for my failures!

Comment: As a cooldown, I had it in a game yesterday, and I always saw the aura return after leaving the room in which I lost it.

Comment: @murgatroid99 so you cannot be saved twice in the same room, interesting...